# In Oracle, is there a function that calculates the difference between two Dates?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle, is there a function that calculates the difference between two Dates? If not, is a way to display the difference between two dates in hours and minutes?

Query:

```
SELECT Round(max((EndDate - StartDate ) * 24), 2) as MaximumScheduleTime,
       Round(min((EndDate - StartDate) * 24), 2)  as MinimumScheduleTime,
       Round(avg((EndDate - StartDate) * 24), 2) as AveragegScheduleTime
FROM table1
```

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 10):

You can subtract two dates in Oracle.  The result is a FLOAT which represents the number of days between the two dates.  You can do simple arithmetic on the fractional part to calculate the hours, minutes and seconds.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000/01/02:12:00:00PM', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam')-TO_DATE('2000/01/01:12:00:00AM', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh:mi:ssam') DAYS FROM DUAL
```

Results in: 1.5

Answer (score 8):

You can use these functions :

1) EXTRACT(element FROM temporal_value)

2) NUMTOYMINTERVAL (n, unit)

3) NUMTODSINTERVAL (n, unit).

For example :

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(end_time - start_time, 'DAY'))
   || ' days ' || 
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(end_time - start_time, 'DAY'))
   ||':'|| 
   EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(end_time - start_time, 'DAY')) 
   ||':'||
   EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(end_time - start_time, 'DAY')) 
   "Lead Time"
FROM table;
```

Comment: NOTE: this solution doesn't report hours for a duration >24hours.  That is, if the difference between end_time and start_time is greater than 24 hours, this returns elapsed hours less any whole 24 hour periods.

Answer (score 4):

> With Oracle Dates, this is pretty
>   trivial, you can get either TOTAL
>   (days, hours, minutes, seconds)
>   between 2 dates simply by subtracting
>   them or with a little mod'ing you can
>   get Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds
>   between.

http://asktom.oracle.com/tkyte/Misc/DateDiff.html

Also, from the above link:

> If you really want 'datediff' in your
>   database, you can just do something
>   like this:

```
SQL> create or replace function datediff( p_what in varchar2, 
  2                                       p_d1   in date, 
  3                                       p_d2   in date ) return number 
  4  as 
  5      l_result    number; 
  6  begin 
  7      select (p_d2-p_d1) * 
  8             decode( upper(p_what), 
  9                     'SS', 24*60*60, 'MI', 24*60, 'HH', 24, NULL ) 
 10       into l_result from dual; 
 11 
 11      return l_result; 
 12  end; 
 13  /
Function created
```

Comment: Please provide usage, what is p_what used for

Answer (score 3):

**Q:** In Oracle, is there a function that calculates the difference between two Dates?

Just subtract one date expression from another to get the difference expressed as a number of days.  The integer portion is the number of whole days, the fractional portion is the fraction of a day.  Simple arithmetic after that, multiply by 24 to get hours.

**Q:** If not, is a way to display the difference between two dates in hours and minutes?

It's just a matter of expressing the duration as whole hours and remainder minutes.

We can go "old school" to get durations in hhhh:mi format using a combination of simple builtin functions:

```
SELECT decode(sign(t.maxst),-1,'-','')||to_char(floor(abs(t.maxst)/60))||
        decode(t.maxst,null,'',':')||to_char(mod(abs(t.maxst),60),'FM00')
         as MaximumScheduleTime
     , decode(sign(t.minst),-1,'-','')||to_char(floor(abs(t.minst)/60))||
        decode(t.minst,null,'',':')||to_char(mod(abs(t.minst),60),'FM00')
         as MinimumScheduleTime
     , decode(sign(t.avgst),-1,'-','')||to_char(floor(abs(t.avgst)/60))
        decode(t.avgst,null,'',':')||to_char(mod(abs(t.avgst),60),'FM00')
         as AverageScheduleTime
  FROM (
         SELECT round(max((EndDate - StartDate) *1440),0) as maxst
              , round(min((EndDate - StartDate) *1440),0) as minst
              , round(avg((EndDate - StartDate) *1440),0) as avgst
           FROM table1 
       ) t
```

---

Yeah, it's fugly, but it's pretty fast.  Here's a simpler case, that shows better what's going on:

```
select dur                              as "minutes"
     , abs(dur)                         as "unsigned_minutes"
     , floor(abs(dur)/60)               as "unsigned_whole_hours"
     , to_char(floor(abs(dur)/60))      as "hhhh"
     , mod(abs(dur),60)                 as "unsigned_remainder_minutes"
     , to_char(mod(abs(dur),60),'FM00') as "mi"
     , decode(sign(dur),-1,'-','')      as "leading_sign"
     , decode(dur,null,'',':')          as "colon_separator"
  from (select round(( date_expr1 - date_expr2 )*24*60,0) as dur
          from ... 
       )
```

(replace `date_expr1` and `date_expr2` with date expressions)

let's unpack this

- `date_expr1 - date_expr2` returns difference in number of days
- multiply by 1440 (24*60) to get duration in minutes
- `round` (or `floor`) to resolve fractional minutes into integer minutes
- divide by 60, integer quotient is hours, remainder is minutes
- `abs` function to get absolute value (change negative values to positive)
- `to_char` format model `FM00` give two digits (leading zeros)
- use `decode` function to format a negative sign and a colon (if needed)

---

The SQL statement could be made less ugly using a PL/SQL function, one that takes <del>two DATE arguments</del> a duration in (fractional) days and returns formatted hhhh:mi

(*untested*)

```
create function hhhhmi(an_dur in number)
return varchar2 deterministic
is
begin
  if an_dur is null then
     return null;
  end if;
  return decode(sign(an_dur),-1,'-','')
    || to_char(floor(abs(an_dur)*24))
    ||':'||to_char(mod((abs(an_dur)*1440),60),'FM00');
end;
```

With the function defined:

```
SELECT hhhhmi(max(EndDate - StartDate)) as MaximumScheduleTime
     , hhhhmi(min(EndDate - StartDate)) as MinimumScheduleTime
     , hhhhmi(avg(EndDate - StartDate)) as AverageScheduleTime
  FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the months_between function to convert dates to the difference in years and then use between the decimal years you are interested:

```
CASE 
WHEN ( ( MONTHS_BETWEEN( TO_DATE(date1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 
                        TO_DATE(date1,'YYYYMMDD'))/12
        )
         BETWEEN Age1DecimalInYears AND Age2DecimalInYears 
      ) 
THEN 'It is between the two dates'
ELSE 'It is not between the two dates' 
END;
```

You may need to change date format to match the a given date format and verify that 31 day months work for your specific scenarios.

References: 
( found on www on 05/15/2015 )

 1. [Oracle/PLSQL: MONTHS_BETWEEN Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/months_between.php)

 2. [Oracle Help Center - MONTHS_BETWEEN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm)