# List of months between two dates, with years in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm storing `months`, `years` and `hours` in different columns, and I want to get the `sum` **hours** when I have entered two dates.

If I have entered two dates suppose `03/01/2013` and `03/31/2015` then I should get the `sum` of all the **hours** between `03-2013` to `03-2015`, including all the `months` and `years` in between.

Comment: A list of months, or a sum of hours? Your question is ambiguous. B.t.w., why are you storing month year and hours in different columns? A date column can contain a full date and time.

Comment: So you want the difference in hours between the first day of the starting month and the first day of the ending month?

Comment: Why on earth would you store those in different columns.  Regardless, you'll probably have to concatonate the values, and use the datediff() function.

Comment: isnt datediff is SQLServer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952149/in-oracle-is-there-a-function-that-calculates-the-difference-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0):

```
select trunc( mod( (date1-date2)*24, 24 ) )  "Hr"
from yourTable
```

Check out [this article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551242712657900129) from AskTom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of the hours, you can take the difference between the dates and multiply by 24:

```
select (date1 - date2) * 24
```

When you subtract two dates in Oracle, you get the difference, expressed as the number of days with fractions (for day parts).